# Expand $(\sqrt{5}+i)^5$, where $i^2=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm getting:

$i^5+5 \sqrt{5} i^4+50 i^3+50 \sqrt{5} i^2+125 i+25 \sqrt{5}$
Is this right?

Comment: So far, so good. Now simplify.

Comment: Who would assign such a masochistic problem?  Scroll down to "alternate forms" and see if it's equal once you've simplified:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%285%29+%2B+i%29%5E5

Comment: $i^2=-1$, so $i^3=-i$, ...

Comment: @Daniel Fischer How would this be simplified? Just replacing $i^2$ with $-1$? What about $i^5$, $i^4$, and $i$? Leave those alone?

Comment: The powers of $i$ follow a pattern. $i^1 = \sqrt{-1}=i$, $i^2 = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=-1$, $i^3 = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=-1\sqrt{-1} = -i$, $i^4 = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}= (-1)(-1) = 1$. Then the pattern repeats.

Comment: Ah, so the answer is: $-20 sqrt(5)+76 i$?

Comment: I edited it. Found the mistake. Look good now?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ (\sqrt a + \sqrt b)^5 = f(a,b)\sqrt a + f(b,a)\sqrt b\,\ $ for $\,\ f(x,y) = x^2\! + 10xy+5 y^2\ $ exploits symmetry to shorten computation, and yields an independent check.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

If $a+ib = r e^{i\, \theta}$,
$(a+ib)^n= r^n e^{n\,i\, \theta}
=r^n (\cos(n\,i\, \theta)+i \sin(n\,i\, \theta))$.